# How to download database model version use BIM360 API

Tags: autodesk-forge

Hi Everyone and Autodesk Forge Team,
Can I know how can I
using just BIM 360 API to do that, do we need model derivative to can download ?

```
https://developer.api.autodesk.com/construction/index/v2/projects/{{PROJECTID}}/indexes/{{VERSIONID}}/manifest
```

[image]

Any help appreciated !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That string values for offsets, attributes, etc. are `derivativeUrn`, so we can download it using [GET  {urn}/manifest/{derivativeurn}/signedcookies](https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/reference/http/urn-manifest-derivativeUrn-signedcookies-GET/).

Here is a code snippet for .NET

```cs
var restSharpClient = new RestClient("https://developer.api.autodesk.com");

RestRequest request = new RestRequest("/modelderivative/v2/designdata/{urn}/manifest/{derivativeUrn}/signedcookies", RestSharp.Method.Get);
request.AddHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + accessToken);
request.AddUrlSegment("urn", urn);
request.AddUrlSegment("derivativeUrn", derivativeUrn);

var response = await restSharpClient.ExecuteAsync(request);

var cloudFrontPolicyName = "CloudFront-Policy";
var cloudFrontKeyPairIdName = "CloudFront-Key-Pair-Id";
var cloudFrontSignatureName = "CloudFront-Signature";

var cloudFrontCookies = response.Headers
                        .Where(x => x.Name == "Set-Cookie")
                        .Select(x => x.Value)
                        .Cast<string>()
                        .ToList();

var cloudFrontPolicy = cloudFrontCookies.Where(value => value.Contains(cloudFrontPolicyName)).FirstOrDefault()?.Trim().Substring(cloudFrontPolicyName.Length + 1).Split(";").FirstOrDefault();
var cloudFrontKeyPairId = cloudFrontCookies.Where(value => value.Contains(cloudFrontKeyPairIdName)).FirstOrDefault()?.Trim().Substring(cloudFrontKeyPairIdName.Length + 1).Split(";").FirstOrDefault();
var cloudFrontSignature = cloudFrontCookies.Where(value => value.Contains(cloudFrontSignatureName)).FirstOrDefault()?.Trim().Substring(cloudFrontSignatureName.Length + 1).Split(";").FirstOrDefault();

var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(response.Content);
var downloadURL = $"{result.url}?Key-Pair-Id={cloudFrontKeyPairId}&Signature={cloudFrontSignature}&Policy={cloudFrontPolicy}";

System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine(downloadURL);

RestRequest requestDownload = new RestRequest(downloadURL, RestSharp.Method.Get);
System.IO.Stream downloadStream = await restSharpClient.DownloadStreamAsync(requestDownload);
string name = derivativeUrn.Substring(derivativeUrn.LastIndexOf('/') + 1);
using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
{
    downloadStream.CopyTo(memoryStream);
    File.WriteAllBytes(name, memoryStream.ToArray());
}
```

You can find more instructions here: https://aps.autodesk.com/blog/download-derivative-files-using-new-signedcookies-api-without-setting-cookies-first-header

Comment: Hi @Eason Kang, do we need pay for process download resouces ?

Comment: No, at this moment, Model Derivative API will charge you for tokens/cloud credits when calling [POST job](https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/reference/http/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/reference/http/job-POST) only. But no guarantee that won't be changed. It might be changed someday in the future. Please refer to https://aps.autodesk.com/pricing for the pricing table, which can provide more accurate info.

Comment: Thank you for your help, it working well with me now.

Comment: Awesome! It's my pleasure!